# VSCodeVim - How to bind text inserts properly?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I'm trying to figure out how to create text inserts in [VSCodeVim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) like:

```
inoremap <leader>sys <esc>ISystem.out.println(<esc>A);
vnoremap <leader>sys yOSystem.out.println(<esc>pA);
```

but the only thing I could come up with is some hacky:

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        // Console.WriteLine
        "before": ["<leader>", "c", "w", "l"],
        "after": ["<Esc>","I","C","o","n","s","o","l","e",".","W","r","i","t","e","L","i","n","e","(","<Esc>","A",")",";"]
    }
```

It does operate nicely. Because there are so many separate keys, the delay creates an animation that is very pleasing XD The problem is writing them. I wrote one for For loops as well and it's not a good experience.

There has to be a better and simpler way of doing this! If I have more than one character inside quotes somewhere, it stops the sequence.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the command `editor.action.insertSnippet`.

```
{
  "vim.insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
      "before": ["<leader>", "c", "w", "l"],
      "commands": [
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": { "snippet": "Console.WriteLine();" }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```